# How to handle checked exceptions inside a functor object in Java

Tags: java, exception, functional-programming

We use the http://jedi.codehaus.org libraries for working with collections and manipulating them in a functional way. We recently came across a problem when doing something similar to the following:

```
public class Address {
    //constructors and stuff

    public KiloWatts electricityConsumed(Duration timePeriod) throw NoElectricitySupply {
        .... does stuff but can throw checked exception
    } 
}
```

given we have a collection of addresses and we wanted to perform something on the UnitsOfElectricity associated with each address, how would you handle the thrown exception e.g.:

```
public KiloWatts totalEnergyConsumed(Address... addresses, final Duration timePeriod) {
     List<KiloWatts> energyConsumedPerAddress = FunctionalPrimitives.collect(addresses, new Functor<Address, KiloWatts>{
         public KiloWatts execute(Address address){
              try {
                  return address.energyConsumed(timePeriod);
              } catch (NoElectricitySupply e) {

                  //What do you do here?

              }
         }
     });
}
```

How would you handle the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not return an [Option<Kilowatts>](http://jedi.codehaus.org/javadoc/jedi/option/Option.html) from the functor so you can return None for the exceptional case? You can then flatten the List<Option<Kilowatts>> to List<Kilowatts> (there is a method on FunctionalPrimitives for that).

Alternatively, if you have control over the energyConsumed method which throws the Exception, replace the thrown Exception with are return type of [Either<String, Kilowatts>](http://jedi.codehaus.org/javadoc/jedi/either/Either.html) (the String can contain an error message or something - I would need to see more to understand what to do there).

Using Either instead of exceptions enables composition, exceptions break composition completely.

Comment: By the way, the use of Either and composeable error handling ultimately leads you to doing it in grown-up languages with applicative functors: http://applicative-errors-scala.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/0.6/pdf/index.pdf and http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you have 2 options:

1. throw a runtime exception (and ignore it); or
2. throw a runtime exception, using it to 'marshall' the checked exception past the interface boundary.

for (2), something like:

```
public KiloWatts totalEnergyConsumed(Address... addresses, final Duration timePeriod) {
    try {
        List<KiloWatts> energyConsumedPerAddress = FunctionalPrimitives.collect(addresses, new Functor<Address, KiloWatts>{
            public KiloWatts execute(Address address){
                try {
                    return address.energyConsumed(timePeriod);
                } catch (NoElectricitySupply e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("internal marshalling exception", e);
                }
           }
       });
    } catch(RuntimeException re) {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work - it's a shame java forces you to do this. I wonder if anyone has come up with a neat clean way of doing this?

Comment: Yeah, Java can be noisy. Try Scala :)

Answer (score 1):

If `NoElectricitySupply` is logically equivalent to zero `KiloWatts`, shouldn't you just return such object?

If they're not quite equivalent, you could create some sort of special `NoKiloWatts` subclass and return an instance of such in the `catch` block.

Comment: I agree. I would liken this to the concept of "not a number" (NaN) that you can encounter when you perform certain math operations.

Comment: Nope - No electricity supply could mean they're not connected, perhaps they use gas or something instead. So zero kilowatts wouldn't necessarily model the situation correctly.